# Print output with setter functions and their values of an object

Tags: java

Suppose if there is a pojo class like below

```
class Student
{
   int id;
   String name;

   public void setId(int id)
   {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public int getId()
   {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setName(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return this.name;
   }
}
```

So suppose in some class I am creating an object like below

```
Student s = new Student();
s.setId(1);
s.setName("Giri");
```

So next I want to print the output like below irrespective of object type, dynamically I need to print.

```
Output: 
s.setId(1);
s.setName("Giri");
```

Is there any logic to print like this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am getting a record from database as an object... I want to print the output like that so that next time I can directly create an object locally instead of calling db... there are so many fields...

Comment: So you are saying that eventually you need to compile and run the code you just outputted? If that's the case, don't. Instead, write the fields into a file on disk. You can use a format like JSON so that you can easily read and write the file with a library such as Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: can you give an example of that @Sweeper

Comment: This question should be closed since asking for a library or tool, which OP is doing, is considered off topic for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void printValues(Object object, String referenceName) {
        Method[] methods = object.getClass().getMethods();
        for(Method method : methods){
            if(isGetter(method))
                try {

                if(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().contentEquals("Date"))
                {
                    if(method.invoke(object)!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(referenceName+"." + method.getName().replace("get", "set")+"(new Date(\""+method.invoke(object)+"\"));");
                    }
                }
                else if(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().contentEquals("long"))
                {
                    System.out.println(referenceName+"." + method.getName().replace("get", "set")+"("+method.invoke(object)+"L);");
                }
                else if(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().contentEquals("String"))
                {
                    if(method.invoke(object)!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(referenceName+"." + method.getName().replace("get", "set")+"(\""+method.invoke(object)+"\");");
                    }

                }
                else if(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().contentEquals("BigInteger"))
                {
                    if(method.invoke(object)!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(referenceName+"." + method.getName().replace("get", "set")+"(new BigInteger(\""+method.invoke(object)+"\"));");
                    }
                }
                else if(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().contentEquals("double"))
                {
                    System.out.println(referenceName+"." + method.getName().replace("get", "set")+"("+method.invoke(object)+");");
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
}

public static boolean isGetter(Method method){
      if(!method.getName().startsWith("get"))      return false;
      if(method.getParameterTypes().length != 0)   return false;  
      if(void.class.equals(method.getReturnType())) return false;
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the print methods in you pojo setters I suppose:

```
   public void setId(int id)
   {
      this.id = id;
      System.out.println("s.setId(" + id + ");");
   }
```

Comment: what if user call function like `s.setId(Integer.parseInt("1"));` ?

Comment: I dont want to modify the Pojo class, I just want to work with the object reference. I am asking for any third party libraries to do like so.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one.

If you are on any JetBrains based IDE (even Android Studio) then you can have a live template as
`Settings`->`Live Templates`->`Add(using + button)`
**Note**: make sure you have `Groovy` enabled for this to work(it is by default).

1. Create a new template as `soutm` which can be the shortcut you'll call. Fill as shown below. Note you can use any other shortcut instead of `soutm` in case of conflict. Template text is `System.out.println($content$);`
   [image: step 1]
2. Click edit variables option and value of content variable defined in step 1 will be
   `groovyScript("def params = _2.collect {it + ' = [\" + ' + it + ' + \"]'}.join(', '); return '\"' + _1 + '() called' + (params.empty  ? '' : ' with: ' + params) + '\"'", methodName(), methodParameters())`
   Hit ok.
   [image: step 2]
3. Last, click on `define` at the bottom to select the language and choose `Java` `Statement`. You can change the `Expand` option. Here it is set to `Tab` which means hitting the tab will expand the shortcut. Uncheck `static imports` option if you don't want to use it.
   [image: step 3]

To test call `soutm` inside any method and it should expand to print all variable data.